# Modification to add in a DB using PHP and AJAX the ID of the current page

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I use a form to post using AJAX to my database the content of the textarea `#inpitField`. The current url is domain.com/product.php?id=1

Even that I add correctly the data to the DB, I want to post the ID of the page also. I am having some problems though. I have posted the entire code for a better understanding.

Thank you for your help.

In my **index.php** I have this form.

```
<form id="tweetForm" action="submit.php" method="post">

<textarea name="inputField" id="inputField"></textarea>
<input class="submitButton inact" name="submit" type="submit" value="update"/>

</form>
```

I send the content of the textarea `#inputField` through AJAX. This is the **script.js**

```
function tweet()
{
    var submitData = $('#tweetForm').serialize();

    $('.counter').html('<img src="img/ajax_load.gif" width="16" height="16" style="padding:12px" alt="loading" />');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "submit.php",
        data: submitData,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(msg){

            if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
            {
                $('ul.statuses li:first-child').before(msg);
                $("ul.statuses:empty").append(msg);

                $('#lastTweet').html($('#inputField').val());

                $('#inputField').val('');
                recount();
            }
        }

    });

}
```

and my **submit.php** file is

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO offers SET tweet='".$_POST['inputField']."',dt=NOW(),company_id=".$myid.",product_id=".I WANT TO ADD THE PRODUCT ID." ");
```

Comment: You mentioned  domain.com/product.php?id=1. What is this page doing?

Comment: @a1ex07 It displays the product with id = a number.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to append your page id to the data you are posting like this:

```
submitData = submitData + "&pageid=" + <?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>;
```

For your code:

```
function tweet(var pageID)
{
    var submitData = $('#tweetForm').serialize();
    submitData = submitData + "&pageid=" + pageID;


    $('.counter').html('<img src="img/ajax_load.gif" width="16" height="16" style="padding:12px" alt="loading" />');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "submit.php",
        data: submitData,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(msg){

            if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
            {
                $('ul.statuses li:first-child').before(msg);
                $("ul.statuses:empty").append(msg);

                $('#lastTweet').html($('#inputField').val());

                $('#inputField').val('');
                recount();
            }
        }

    });

}
```

Called as:

```
tweet("<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>")
```

Comment: Hello, can you be more clear? because there is something else in submitData

Comment: @mtopia I added an example using your original code. Let me know if that's what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
function tweet()
{
    var urlid = window.location.href.split('?id=', 2)[1];

    $('#tweetForm').append('<input type="text" name="id" value="'+urlid+'" />');

    var submitData = $('#tweetForm').serialize();

    $('.counter').html('<img src="img/ajax_load.gif" width="16" height="16" style="padding:12px" alt="loading" />');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "submit.php",
        data: submitData,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(msg){

            if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
            {
                $('ul.statuses li:first-child').before(msg);
                $("ul.statuses:empty").append(msg);

                $('#lastTweet').html($('#inputField').val());

                $('#inputField').val('');
                recount();
            }
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. My question is how can it get all the digits and not only the first two ?

Comment: @mtopia that will get you all the digits in the url.